# An application of J.-L. Lion's Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be three Banach spaces with norms $\|\cdot\|_X$, $\|\cdot\|_Y$,$\|\cdot\|_Z$. Assume that $X\subset Y$ with compact "injection" and that $Y\subset Z$ with continuous injection. Then

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists  C_{\epsilon}\geq0  $$

Satisfying $$\|u\|_Y\leq \epsilon \|u\|_X+C_{\epsilon}\|u\|_Z \ \ \forall u \in X.$$

My question are

I) Where can I find a proof of this result?

II) As a consequence of that how to prove

$$\max_{[0,1]}|u|\leq \epsilon\max_{[0,1]}|u'|+C_{\epsilon}\|u\|_{L^1{[0,1]}} \forall \in C^1({[0,1]})?$$

Comment: You can find this in Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, 2011, Exercise 6.12, pag. 173. I think there are also the answers for the exercise in the back of the book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the result were not true, we would be able to find $\varepsilon_0>0$ and a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset X$ such that $\lVert u_n\rVert_Y=1$ and $1\geq \varepsilon_0\lVert u_n\rVert_X+n\lVert u_n\rVert_Z$. Since the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $X$ and the inclusion $X\subset Y$ is compact, we can find a subsequence denoted $\{v_k\}$ which converges to $v$ in $Y$. Since the inclusion $Y\subset Z$ is continuous, $v_n\to v$ in $Z$. This gives a contradiction since $\lVert v_k\rVert_Z\leq \frac 1k$ so $v=0$ but $\lVert v_k\rVert_Y=1$ so $\lVert v\rVert_Y$.

For the second question, take $X$ the Banach space of continuously differentiable functions endowed with the norm $\lVert u\rVert_X:=\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u'\rVert_{\infty}$, $Y$ the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with the norm $\lVert u\rVert_Y:=\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}$ and $Z=L^1[0,1]$ with the natural norm. For a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we get a constant $K_{\varepsilon}$ such that for all $u\in X$: $\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}\leq \varepsilon(\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u'\rVert_{\infty})+K_{\varepsilon}\lVert u\rVert_{L^1}$ so fo $\varepsilon< 1$
$$(1-\varepsilon)\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}\leq \varepsilon\lVert u'\rVert_{\infty}+K_\varepsilon\lVert u\rVert_{L^1},$$ 
and so 
$$\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}\lVert u'\rVert_{\infty}+\frac{K_{\varepsilon}}{1-\varepsilon}\lVert u\rVert_{L^1}.$$

Comment: For a reference (containing the same proof of the abstract result), see e.g. Lemma 1.1, page 106 of Showalter's *[Monotone operators in Banach spaces and nonlinear partial differential equations](http://books.google.com/books?id=DpTX7ibZolIC&pg=PA106)*.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for the reference, I didn't know this book. For the last part, the inconvenient of this method is that we don't know the constant $K_{\varepsilon}$, whereas it's possible to determine it with a direct approach.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\| u_n\|_X$ is bounded? we have $\| \cdot \|_Y \leq C\| \cdot \|_X$ not the other way around.

Comment: @Jose27 We have $\lVert u_n\rVert_X\leq \frac 1{\varepsilon_0}$.

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: But in the second question how did we get the right bound? We only have $\frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}$ on the RHS, right? How do we go from there to just $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @gtoques Define $1>\varepsilon':=\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+1}>0$. So, you can apply the result for $\varepsilon'$ and get the result you want.